# Tempus Dominus 6 time picker 24h

Tags: javascript, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

i use [Tempus Dominus](https://getdatepicker.com) for select time in my website.

i want to remove AM, PM text from time picker and have 00-23 instead.

screenshot:

[image]

my code:

```
$('#datepickerTime').tempusDominus({
            useCurrent: false,
            stepping: 15,
            display: {
                viewMode: 'clock',
                buttons: {
                    close: true,
                },
                components: {
                    useTwentyfourHour: true,
                    decades: false,
                    year: false,
                    month: false,
                    date: false,
                    hours: true,
                    minutes: true,
                    seconds: false
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Version 6 of TempusDominus explicitly removes dependency/compatibility with jQuery (see [here](https://getdatepicker.com/6/examples/)), which is what you're using to initialise your picker.

If you instantiate it like this it will work as expected:

```
new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(document.getElementById('datepickerTime'), {
    useCurrent: false,
    stepping: 15,
    display: {
        viewMode: 'clock',
        buttons: {
            close: true,
        },
        components: {
            useTwentyfourHour: true,
            decades: false,
            year: false,
            month: false,
            date: false,
            hours: true,
            minutes: true,
            seconds: false
        }
    }
});
```